# Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"\345\244\204\347\220\206\34...."

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm using hyperledger fabric 1.4 to writing the chaincode named task.go.In the task.go, there is a function I wrote called transferBalance, which implements the transfer between two accounts.

func (t* TaskChaincode) transferBalance(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface,args[] string) pb.Response {

```
if len(args) != 3{
    return shim.Error("Wrong number of given parameters")
}

source := args[0]
target := args[1]
amount,err := strconv.Atoi(args[2])

if err != nil{
    return shim.Error("Format conversion failed")
}

if amount <= 0{
    return shim.Error("The number of designated transfer tokens must be greater than 0")
}


sacc,err := stub.GetState(source)
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error("Failed to obtain account information according to the specified account")
}

if sacc == nil {
    return shim.Error("The source account does not exist")
}


tacc,err := stub.GetState(target)
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error("Failed to obtain account information according to the specified account")
}

if tacc== nil {
    return shim.Error("The source account does not exist")
}

sval,err := strconv.Atoi(string(sacc))
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error("An error occurred while processing the source account balance")
}

tval,err := strconv.Atoi(string(tacc))
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error("An error occurred while processing the target account balance")
}

if sval < amount{
    return shim.Error("Insufficient balance")
}

sval = sval - amount
tval = tval + amount

err = stub.PutState(source,[]byte(strconv.Itoa(sval)))  
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error("Failed to save the status of the source account after the transfer")
}

err = stub.PutState(target,[]byte(strconv.Itoa(tval)))  
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error("Failed to save the status of the target account after the transfer")
}

return shim.Success([]byte("Successful tr"))
```

}

And I successfully installed the chain code, and executed the following command to call the above function.
peer chaincode invoke -n taskcc -c '{"Args":["transferBalance","user1_account","user2_account","2"]}' -C myc

I'm getting an error shown below:
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"\345\244\204\347\220\206\345\216\237\350\264\246\346\210\267\344\275\231\351\242\235\346\227\266\345\217\221\347\224\237\351\224\231\350\257\257"

I don't know how to solve this problem. And I want to know what the numbers in the above error mean.
How should I try to find the source of the error and solve it. Please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Well the message looks like it's an octet string, which converts to chinese and that chinese message translates to english as "An error occurred while processing the original account balance"

Comment: Interpreting the numbers suggested in the question is as follows.[octal-to-text](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/octal/)

Comment: `户余额时发生错误` This error log occurred. Can you show me the relevant code?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I think I've found a solution to the problem.

Comment: Can you please share the solution to this problem? I'm facing the same error.